# How can I pass the value of total when using bind method for the forms?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, next.js

I have this form and I wanted to pass the value of total.

**For the `total`:**
I wa already able to pass the value of the `cart` which is an array.

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined);
  const calculateTotal = () => {
    return cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, 0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const calculatedTotal = calculateTotal();
    setTotal(calculatedTotal);
  },[cart])

const  addOrderInfo = addCustomerOrder.bind(null, cart)
```

**Inside the return function for the forms:**

```
 <form action={addOrderInfo}>
   //input fields here
</form>
```

**Submission of the form:**

```
export default async function addCustomerOrder(cart: any, formData: FormData): Promise<{ message: string }> {    
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const supabase = createServerActionClient({ cookies: () => cookieStore })
    console.log(formData, "formData")
    console.log(cart, "prev state")

    try{
       //rest of the data here
        return {  message: `Succesfully added the data` }
    }catch(e){
        return {message: "Failed to submit the form."}
    }

}
```

Comment: try using form hidden input 

 ```<input type="hidden" name="total" value={total} />```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some stuff to clean up here that will help a bit before getting to the root of the problem.

`total` is derived from the state item `cart` so actually, `total` should not be using `useState` at all. Doing so "works" but is a code smell as you are manually managing state computed from some other state. That tends to lead to bugs down the line if you ever forget to keep them in sync. `useMemo` is the correct tool for this.

On to the main problem. There's no need to do stuff like `addCustomerOrder.bind(null, cart)`, which is not a pattern you usually see when doing this sort of thing in React. You can simply define a new closure that includes the extra piece of information and pass that to the main handler.

Replace *all* of the top block you posted with:

```
  const total = useMemo<number>(() => {
    const calculateTotal = () => {
      return cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, 0);
    };

    return calculateTotal();
  }, [cart])
```

Replace the form wrapper with

```
 <form action={(data) => addCustomerOrder(cart, total, data)}>
   //input fields here
</form>
```

Now change the signature of `addCustomerOrder`:

```
export default async function addCustomerOrder(cart: any, total: number, formData: FormData): Promise<{ message: string }> {
```

Comment: Thanks, but I also have a `message` in the function `addCustomerOrder`, my problem now is how I can display the `message`